# Get how many hours, minutes and seconds until midnight in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to get how many hours, minutes and seconds until Midnight.
I have the following code:

```
    _midnight = DateTime.Today; // this is th midnight
    Debug.Log("current " + DateTime.Now);
    Debug.Log("TimeToMidnight " + _midnight.Subtract(DateTime.Now));
```

This how I get as a Debug message:

- current 9/8/2020 3:09:41 PM
- TimeToMidnight -15:09:41.5144330

As you can see, the time to Midnight is completely wrong. I'm I missing something?

Comment: Midnight is the beginning of the day, not the end.  You want `DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);`

Comment: You want tomorrow as midnight so add one day : DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem!