# Need to determine how many hours, minutes and seconds until midnight

Tags: c#

I need to get a countdown timer in C# (VS2022) showing how many hours, minutes and seconds until midnight. I have found several similar questions on Stack Overflow, such as [Get how many hours, minutes and seconds until midnight in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63794696/get-how-many-hours-minutes-and-seconds-until-midnight-in-c-sharp) but the answers always display in milliseconds, not HH:MM:SS. What I want to do is show the hours, minutes and seconds until midnight in a label on a form.
It will say something like "Time Until Midnight: 04:25:30".

Comment: Did you try out the suggested solution and step through the operation? If you subtract two DateTimes, you get a TimeSpan (which you should be able to see in the debugger - if not create a temporary variable) . Then the question becomes "How do I format a TimeSpan?" The rules are quirky, but easy to find